# My batch launched by Inno Setup installer says "The system cannot find the file specified" while it is right there

Tags: inno-setup

In my Inno setup script, I have this line:

```
[Files]
Source: C:\CLIENTS\ACSORDER\DeployAcsOrder\installSQL\*; DestDir: "{code:GetDir|0}\installSQL";
       
[Run]
Filename: {code:GetDir|0}\installSQL\installSQL.bat Parameters: {code:GetDir|0}\installSQL; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,LumisTraiteur}; StatusMsg: Installation SQL serveur...; Flags: runhidden
```

```pascal
[Code]
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;

function GetDir(Param: String): String;
begin
  Result := DirPage.Values[StrToInt(Param)];
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  { create a directory input page }
  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(
    wpSelectDir, 'Moteur base de données', 'Choisir un emplacement de destination du setupSQL', 'SubCaption', False, '');
  { add directory input page items }
  DirPage.Add('Répertoire installation SQL');
  { assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if }
  { there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders }
  { of your choice }
  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Répertoire installation SQL', 'C:\');
end;

procedure RegisterPreviousData(PreviousDataKey: Integer);
begin
  { store chosen directories for the next run of the setup }
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Directory1', DirPage.Values[0]);
end;
...
```

But when the the installation is finished, it pop up an error saying:

> Unable to execute file:
> C:\folderIchoose\installSQL.bat Parameters: C:\folderIchoose\
>
> CreateProcess failed; code 2.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

When I go to `C:\folderIchoose`, the `installSQL.bat` is right there, when I try with a cmd start and the parameter, it works... why would it say it can't find the file?

I want to launch my batch with as parameter the name of the folder my bach is (not sure to be clear...)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon before the `Parameters:`. So it is considered to be a part of the batch file path.

It should be:

```
[Run]
Filename: {code:GetDir|0}\installSQL\installSQL.bat; Parameters: ...
```